# Centering <div> left to a sidebar

Tags: html, css

I apologize, but unfortunately I couldn't find any answer.

I have this code:

```css
#wrapper {
 width: 844px;
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 text-align: left;
}
#posts {
 width: 844px;
 float: left;
}
.entry {
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 10px;
 float: left;
 width: 400px;
}
#sidebar {
 position: fixed;
 width: 250px;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 display: table; /* needs to center stuff vertically inside of the sidebar */
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id='wrapper'>
 <div id='posts'>
   {block:Posts}
    <div class='entry'>
     <!-- Tumblr posts -->
    </div>
   {/block:Posts}
  </div>
</div>
<div id='sidebar'>
 <!-- Stuff in the sidebar -->
</div>
</body>
```

I want to keep my `#posts` centered in the area, where no sidebar is given. I mean `#posts` has to be centered in its own container. In the code I've shown it goes over the sidebar.

Comment: Your snippet doesnt reproduce the problem specified in the question..please edit the question and show us the exact problem that you are facing..

Comment: @Lal Why doesn't it reproduce?

Comment: @user can you recreate your problem here http://jsfiddle.net/kLm9xn5f/1/

Comment: @Lal http://jsfiddle.net/kLm9xn5f/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not so clear but i have coded as per my understanding [check this link](https://jsfiddle.net/pet9mv1g/)

### HTML

```
   <div id='wrapper'>
        <div id='posts'>
                {block:Posts}
                    <div class='entry'>
                        <!-- Tumblr posts -->
                    </div>
                {/block:Posts}
         </div>
<div id='sidebar'>
        <!-- Stuff in the sidebar -->
    </div>
    </div>
```

## CSS

```
             #wrapper {
                    width: 600px;
                    display: block;
                    margin-left: auto;
                    margin-right: auto;
                    text-align: center;
                    float:center;
                }
                #posts {
                    width: 70%;
                    text-align:center;
                    background-color:yellow;
                }
                .entry {
                    border: 1px solid black;
                    padding: 10px;
                    /* float: center; */
                    width: 200px;
                    margin-left:auto;
                    margin-right:auto;
                }
                #sidebar {
                    position: fixed;
                    width: 30%;
                    background-color:cyan;
                    height: 100%;
                    top: 0px;
                    right: 0px;
                    display: table; /* needs to center stuff vertically inside of the sidebar */
                }
```

> Use width of the wrapper as per your need and rest will adjust automatically.
>
> follow the link above to see the live example. I have used background colors to visualize the area properly, you may remove if you want.